# C++ using a **pointer in a function argument not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I have a function that expects a pointer array as such:

```
void SortResistance(MyClass ** pointerArray, int arraySize);
```

and does a bubble sort.  Inside that function I can access any two array elements using:

```
MyClass * item1 = *pointerArray + i;  
MyClass * item2 = *pointerArray + i + 1;
```

Where I'm iterating over the array. So far so good. When I swap the values using a very simple swap function such as:

```
void Swap(MyClass ** item1, MyClass ** item2);
```

The values on the pointers swap as expected.

My problem is that I don't know how to reassign them back to pointerArray.

This doesn't work:

```
*(pointerArray + i) = item1;
*(pointerArray + i + 1) = item2;
```

(Well, it works when i equals 0 but otherwise it just shifts the pointee, not its value.)

I'm wondering if anyone would please help me with this problem. The function prototypes cannot be changed so I'm assuming they are correct.

Here is the gory detail in the simplest possible implementation. Thank you very much for your responses.

I was asked to look at something similar to the following declarations and to implement:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //TODO: instantiate an array of pointers and sort them using the below
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    double value;
    string name;
}

void Sort(MyClass ** myArray, int arraySize)
{
    //TODO: implement bubble sort
}

void Swap(MyClass ** pointer1, MyClass ** pointer2)
{
    MyClass *temp = *pointer1;
    *pointer1 = *pointer2;
    *pointer2 = temp;
}
```

My solution, based on something like the following http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ would be something like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    double value;
    string name;
};

void Swap(MyClass ** pointer1, MyClass ** pointer2)
{
    MyClass *temp = *pointer1;
    *pointer1 = *pointer2;
    *pointer2 = temp;

}

void Sort(MyClass ** myArray, int arraySize)
{
    bool done = false; // this flag will be used to check whether we have to continue the algorithm

    while (!done)
    {
        done = true; // assume that the array is currently sorted
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) // for every element in the array  
        {
            MyClass * p1 = *myArray + i;
            MyClass * p2 = *myArray + i + 1;

            //MyClass * p1 = *(myArray + i);
            //MyClass * p2 = *(myArray + i + 1);
            //MyClass * p1 = myArray[i];
            //MyClass * p2 = myArray[i + 1];

            if ( p1->value > p2->value ) // compare the current element with the following one
            {
                // They are in the wrong order, swap them
            Swap(&p1, &p2);
                //Swap(*(&myArray + i), *(&myArray + i + 1));
            //Swap(myArray + i, myArray + i + 1);

            *(myArray + i) = p1;
            *(myArray + i + 1) = p2;

                done = false; // since we performed a swap, the array needs to be checked to see if it is sorted
                               // this is done in the next iteration of the while
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    MyClass item1; item1.name = "item1"; item1.value = 25.5;
    MyClass item2; item2.name = "item2"; item2.value = 15.5;
    MyClass myItems[2]; myItems[0] = item1; myItems[1] = item2;

    MyClass * myPointerToItemArray = myItems;
    Sort(&myPointerToItemArray, 2);
}
```

The code compiles fine under VS 2010. As you can see, everything goes well until I have to reassign the new set of pointers to the array. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm starting to think the declarations have to be modified to make this work.

Comment: I will edit this question in a bit to include a full working sample.

Comment: Why do you even call the Swap function? Doesn't a simple `myArray[i]  =p2;myArray[i+1] = p1;` work?

Comment: function declarations where required. Finally figured it out. See my answer. You're correct except for the fact you're swapping values, not pointer references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while I was able to make it work. The code for the example problem above is given here. Thank you all for your suggestions.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    double value;
    string name;
};

void Swap(MyClass ** pointer1, MyClass ** pointer2)
{
    MyClass *temp = *pointer1;
    *pointer1 = *pointer2;
    *pointer2 = temp;

}

void Sort(MyClass ** myArray, int arraySize)
{
    //sorting
    bool done = false;

    while (!done)
    {
        done = true; // assume that the array is currently sorted
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) // for every element in the array  
        {
            if (myArray[i]->value > myArray[i + 1]->value) 
            {
                Swap(&myArray[i], &myArray[i + 1]);
                //MyClass temp = *myArray[i];
                //*myArray[i] = *myArray[i + 1];
                //*myArray[i + 1] = temp;
                done = false;
            }

        }

    }

};

void main()
{
    MyClass item1; item1.name = "item1"; item1.value = 25.5;
    MyClass item2; item2.name = "item2"; item2.value = 15.5;
    MyClass item3; item3.name = "item3"; item3.value = 10.5;
    MyClass * myItems[3]; myItems[0] = &item1; myItems[1] = &item2; myItems[2] = &item3;

    MyClass ** dp = myItems;

    Sort(dp, 3); 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier if you treat it as an actual array rather than a pointer, e.g.

```
MyClass* item1 = pointerArray[i];
MyClass* item2 = pointerArray[i + 1];
```

and:

```
pointerArray[i] = item1;
pointerArray[i + 1] = item2;
```

You don't need to modify the function prototypes to do this.

Comment: This solution is also incorrect. Same problem as Lochemage's response below. The first term works for i = 0, the second is an invalid pointer.

Comment: If the second is an invalid pointer then you are exceeding the bounds of your array and you have an error in your bubble sort.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question and the problem will become clear. It is in fact a bad pointer, but not an array bounds problem.

Comment: "Bad pointer" is meaningless without further details. If `pointerArray[i]` is valid then `pointerArray[i+1]` will be valid as well unless it exceeds the bounds. Or do you mean the thing it points to (`*pointerArray[i]`) is invalid? If that's the case the error has nothing to do with your sort function.

Comment: Please see my corrected example with code above and the problem will become evident.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've done a little debugging in my own compiler... try

```
MyClass * item1 = *(pointerArray + i);
MyClass * item2 = *(pointerArray + i + 1);
```

And leave the rest of the code the same.

Comment: Compiles correctly. Same problem as below. I will edit the question to include a complete working sample in about an hour. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

try catching the array values in a reference:

```
MyClass &* item1 = *pointerArray + i;
MyClass &* item2 = *pointerArray + i + 1;
```

then you shouldn't need to re-assign the values after the fact.

EDIT:
What you were doing is essentially making a copy to the pointers in item1, item2.  Swapping them swapped the copies, but not the original.  You could try omitting the copies and just doing something like this:

```
Swap(&(*pointerArray + i), &(*pointerArray + i + 1));
```

Comment: Pointer to reference doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, a bit rusty with c++, it's been a while since I've messed in that language.  I hope the idea is there though, however the syntax is.

Comment: The first one gives me an error: pointer to error is not allowed. The second one gives me a "expression must be lvalue" error

Comment: It's very possible I have the order backwards, it may need to be *&

Comment: No, sorry. Once again the second pointer (after i equals 0) points to an invalid memory location. It's affecting the pointer itself, not the underlying value.

Comment: Also, for the last bit of code: you are incrementing the double pointer pointerArray first by i and then you are de-referencing it to get the array.  What may work better is to de-reference first, then increment. (*pointerArray)+ i = item1;

Comment: if you are using my commented references, don't do that last part of code.  If you are sticking with your own code, that last bit should be changed to the above.

Comment: Understood what you're saying, but no, does not work. The expression *(pointerArray + i) = item1 shifts the pointer. The expression you last wrote (*pointerArray) + i = item1 is invalid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31434/discussion-between-lochemage-and-tomato)